# Resizing UIView with UIToolbar do not resize simultaneously

Tags: ios, uiview, resize, uitoolbar, autoresize

I have created a UIView with a UIToolbar both programmatically and with IB.  I try to resize the UIView but the tool bar resizes first and make it obvious that there are 2 views.  Can anyone tell me how to resize both view simultaneously so that it give the appearance that the UIView and toolbar are one? I have set all the appropriate masks.  The code below is called on the UIView from the UIView class.

Thanks!!!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: .3 animations:^ {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 20;
    frame.size.height = 900;
    frame.size.width = 768;
    self.frame = frame;
   }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate both at the same time:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: .3 animations:^ {
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 900.0, 768.0);
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 900.0, 768.0);
}];
```

Or use some NSLayoutConstraint to achieve equal frames.